# Saving a date into a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I am developing a small Windows Phone application. It needs to be able to save the current date as the name of the text file. Right now, I have the following code:

```
{
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            isf.CreateDirectory("Data");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Create, isf));
            sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            sw.Close();
            StreamReader sr = null;
            try
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, isf));
                textBlock1.Text = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Close();
            }

            catch
            {
                textBox1.Text = "When you make a Journal entry, it will be displayed here.";
            }
        }
        private void textBlock1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            isf.CreateDirectory("Data");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Create, isf));
            sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBlock1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            StreamReader sr = null;
            try
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, isf));
                textBlock1.Text = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Close();
            }

            catch
            {
                textBlock1.Text = "When you make a Journal entry, it will be displayed here.";
            }
        }
```

Sorry, the "Embed Code" function isn't liking my code.

Edit: Thanks to whoever/whatever fixed the "Embed Code" function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using hard-coded `myFile.txt`, simply buid a file name using `DateTime.Today`. For example:

```
string fileName = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Then you can create your `StreamWriter`:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, isf));
```

Comment: Thanks. The last bit (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter...) was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am understanding your question.  You want to create a new text file each day and name the file something like "03-09-2011.txt".

You can do:

```
var fileName = string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}.txt", DateTime.Now);
```

This will get a file name like I mentioned above.

I would also probably use Path.Combine:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var directory = "Data";
isf.CreateDirectory(directory);
var fileName = string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}.txt", DateTime.Now);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Path.Combine(directory, filName), FileMode.Create, isf));
sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
sw.Close();
```

That will take care of adding the "\" between the paths, and that way you have the directory name and file name separate (I always seem to need these later anyways).

This has the added benefit that you can prepend or append to the name easily:

```
var fileName = string.Format("This is the file for {0:MM-dd-yyyy}.txt", DateTime.Now);
```